# Create repeatable byte array of Go struct which contains a pointer

Tags: go, struct, encoding, hash, byte

I want to be able to create repeatable byte arrays of structs in Go so I can hash them and then verify that hash at some point.

I am currently following this simple approach to create a byte array from a struct with:

```
[]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%v", struct))...)
```

This works perfectly until my struct holds an embedded struct with a pointer, for example:

```
type testEmbeddedPointerStruct struct {
    T *testSimpleStruct
}
```

In my tests this creates a different byte array each time, I think it may be because with the pointer the address in memory changes each time?

Is there a way of creating a repeatable byte array digest even if the struct holds a pointer?

Thanks

Comment: For the pointer, `%v` will print the address where the original value stored. You should write a function for deep dereferencing the value for pointer.

Comment: "Is there a way of creating a repeatable byte array digest even if the struct holds a pointer?" Yes of course, you have to implement it, probably with reflection. Note that the general case is undoable or how would you process a channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... I think it may be because with the pointer the address in memory changes ...

That's the obvious candidate, yes.  You have chosen a very simple encoding, in which pointer fields are encoded as a hexadecimal representation of the pointer, rather than any value found at the target of the pointer.

> Is there a way of creating a repeatable byte array digest even if the struct holds a pointer?

You may need to define more precisely what "repeat of same value" means to you,<sup>1</sup> but in general, this is really an encoding problem.  The `encoding/gob` package could perhaps give you an encoding you would like here, though note that unlike `%v` formatting, it encodes only exported struct fields *and* keeps the various names.  It has the effect of "flattening" any pointer data, but won't work for cyclic data structures.

(You can write your own simpler encoder that simply follows pointers when it encounters them, and otherwise works like `%v`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>For example, suppose you have:

```golang
type T struct {
    I int
    P *Sub
}
type Sub struct {
    J int
}
// ...
s2 := Sub{2}
s3 := Sub{3}
t1 := T{1, &s2}
t2 := T{1, &s3}
```

Obviously printing t1 and t2 (while flattening away pointers) produces an encoded version of `{1 2}` and `{1 3}` respectively, so these are not the same value.  However, if we change `s3` itself to:

```golang
s3 := Sub{2}
```

we now have two different entities, `t1` and `t2`, that both "contain as a value" `{1 2}`.  In Go, `t1` and `t2` are different because their pointers differ.  Their values, in other words, are different.  In the proposed *encoding*, `t1` and `t2` both encode the same, so they are the *same* value.

This is the kind of thing that occurs with pointers: the underlying data may be the same—the "same value" in one sense—but the objects holding those values may differ in location, so that if one object is modified, the other is not.  If you run such objects through an encode-then-decode process that makes them *share* the *pointed-to* value, you may give up the ability to modify one object without modifying the other, or to distinguish between them.

Since you get to choose how to do the encoding, *you* get to decide exactly what you want to have happen here.  But you must make that choice on purpose, not just accidentally.